# x86 Modrm/Sib/Displacement bytes for opcode '89'

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm developing a disassembler for the 32-bit x86 instruction set. My code currently decodes most 1 and 2 byte opcodes correctly, but I have run into a problem. When I compare the output of my code to Objdump, I find that Objdump sees the following:-

```
89 14 98                mov    %edx,(%eax,%ebx,4)

8b 45 d8                mov    -0x28(%ebp),%eax
```

On the other hand, my code gives:-

```
89 14 98 8B 45 D8 89   MOV.
```

From my understanding of Intels documentation (The Modrm and Sib addressing form tables in particular), this byte stream should be interpreted as:-

```
89 - The opcode
14 - The Modrm byte
98 - The Sib byte specified by the Modrm byte (as shown in Intels Modrm addressing table)
8B 45 D8 89 - The four byte displacement specified by the Sib byte (as shown in Intels Sib addressing table).
```

Objdump says that there are no displacement bytes, but both my code and Intels documentation appear (to me at least) to say otherwise.

If anyone could point out where my error is, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Mod/RM byte 0x14 breaks down into Mod=00 Reg=010 R/M=100.

In http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf Table 2-2 (page labeled "2-6", actually page 36 of the PDF) it shows Mod=00 R/M=100 as being a SIB with no displacement.

I can't be sure which part you've misread since you didn't specify the documentation you're using. There are lots of different Intel manuals.

Comment: Hi Alan,thanks for the speedy reply. I think that my error was that I assumed that any Sib byte could potentially have displacement bytes, regardless of the Modrm byte that specified it. When I see, for example, [EAX*4] in the SIB addressing table, I assume that this is this telling me that I require a 4 byte displacement. Are you saying that this displacement should already be specified in the Modrm, and that I do not need to check the contents of SIB bytes to determine displacement bytes? Also, my documentation is Intel (R) 64 and IA-32 architecture software developers manual. Thanks.

Comment: The `*4` has nothing to do with the displacement. It literally means that the value of EAX is multipled by 4. (Probably because EAX is an index into an array of 4-byte-wide entities)

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused. I have changed my code so that a Modrm byte of 0x14 is interpreted as a SIB with no displacement. However I then find that Objdump sees ff 14 85 14 4f 05 08    call   *0x8054f14(,%eax,4). In this case, it doesn't think that a Modrm of 0x14 contains no displacement bytes. Also, beneath the Sib addressing table (Table 2-3) it says that * specifies a disp32 or disp8, depending on the value of MOD.

Comment: mod=00 base=101 is a very special case in which there's a displacement not specified directly in the modrm byte. I think that's as complicated as it gets...

Comment: Ahh that does make sense to me, since opcode 0xff is an opcode extension that uses the reg field. I don't suppose you know where in the documentation I might find information about these special cases? I've had a quick look through the contents, but nothing immediately grabs me (Its a long document to search in the dark lol).

Comment: It's all there in the tables, once you learn how to read them. The footnote you already mentioned explains that mod=00 base=101 is a special case. In the pdf I used, section A.2 in appendix A is a good guide to decoding.